# input for md5 hashfunction in file checksum application

Tags: java, security, md5

I understand md5 is mostly used for file checksum and we can use following code in java to generate md5 digest.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
  DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
  /* Read stream to EOF as normal... */
}
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

But I'd like to know what exactly is the input of the md function? the meta data of file or the text in file?

Comment: Your question implies that an inputstream con only be created for a file - but that's wrong. So ask yourself: what is the content of the input stream?

Answer (score 0):

The input is the text in the file.